obs-websocket の使い方について
現在Pythonでobs-websocketというモジュールを使用しているのですが、下記のURLに記載されている"SceneCreated"を使用しようと考え
ws.call(
        events.SceneCreated(
            sceneName="test1",
            sceneUuid="1",
            isGroup=False,
        )
    )

とコードを書いたのですが
TypeError: Baseevents.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sceneName'

とエラーが出ました。
"sceneName"をどのように書き換えればうまく動くかお手数ですが下記のURLを参考に教えてください。
https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket/blob/master/docs/generated/protocol.md#scenecreated

もう少し情報が必要と思われます。質問内容だと何かのプログラムからevents.SceneCreated(...)を呼び出そうとしているように見えますが、方向性が逆ではないですか？ eventsとか...edという名前が示すように、OBSから呼び出されるイベントのハンドラ処理のことではありませんか？ EventHandler.cpp#L496 類似の処理やモジュールとしてこんなものが検索して見つかるので参考になるかもしれません。Events - obsws-python, obs-websocket-py/samples/events.py

説明不足ですみませんでした...私の解釈が間違っていたようです
たくさんの例を提示していただきありがとうございます！

問題は解決済みですか？ そうでない場合、以下の情報を追記すると、回答が得られ易いかも知れません。

使用しているというモジュール「obs-websocket」のURL（公式サイト、あるいはPyPIやGitHubのページなど）
コード中の ws や events が何なのか解るような箇所（import している所など）

